# Can't use the url given by the getDownloadURL in a Image.network()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter with `image_picker` and `firebase_storage` to store an image and then download the link to place in a `firestore` database. Here is my current code:

```dart
final picker = ImagePicker();
final file = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final fileBytes = await file!.readAsBytes();

var reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(file.name);
await reference.putData(fileBytes);

String url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Images').add({
  'imageUrl': url,
  'timeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
});
```

The variable `url` has a value like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject.appspot.com/o/example.png?alt=media&token=image-token`.

I want to display the images using a `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Images')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final image = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
          return Image.network(image["imageUrl"]);
        }
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
      );
    }

    return const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
)
```

But I am getting the error

```dart
ImageCodecException: Failed to load network image. 
Image URL:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject.appspot.com/o/example.png?alt=media&token=image-token 
Server response code: 400
```

for every image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of research, and screaming to my computer, I found the [answer to my problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73109).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated your setup and got your desired result. It looks like you were not awaiting for this promise to be resolved hence it was not getting stored in the firestore document.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Images').add({ // ⇐ 
  'imageUrl': url,
  'timeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
});
```

Here’s the my recreated code :

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> imageStreams =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('images').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void pickImage() async {
      final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      final image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        //Upload to Firebase
        final fileBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
        Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(image.name);
        final snapshot = await reference.putData(fileBytes);
        String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('images').add({
          'imageUrl': downloadUrl,
          'timeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
        });
      } else {
        print('No Image Path Received');
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: imageStreams,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final image = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return Image.network(image["imageUrl"]);
              });
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: pickImage,
        tooltip: 'Upload Image',
        child: const Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Reference : [**Adding Documents**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#adding-documents)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it gives the same error...